# Shapiro–Wilk test for non-normal distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, statistical-power

The Shapiro–Wilk test makes use of the correlation between the data (a.k.a. sample quantile) $x$ and its theoretical quantile $m$. As far as I'm concerned, it's a normality test simply because the theoretical quantile is calculated from a normal distribution, or more precisely, `m <- qnorm((rank(x) - 0.5) / length(x))`.

My question is, can we use it to test other distributions, as long as the theoretical quantile is calculated accordingly? What about its power in this use case?

Comment: The use of quantile-quantile plots implies that correlation between observed and predicted quantiles makes sense. But a similar test for other distributions wouldn’t be a Shapiro-Wilk test. More fruitful in practice to simulate from your expected distribution to get a portfolio of plots.

Comment: @NickCox You mean the critical points must be re-calculated for each distribution separately? Yeah that would work...

Comment: Indeed; that is the implication. It's typically a lot easier to calculate expected quantiles and use them in QQ plots.